# color change on condition in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to change the color based on a condition.
I display the n number of cards the card background must change based on the condition.

```js
users.map((item)=>{

if(item.userType == "private"){

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--customcolor',"yellow");

}

else if(item.userType == "private"){

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--customcolor',"blue");

}

});
```

```css
 :root {
    --customcolor: red;
  }
  
  .oddmes {
    background-color: var(--customcolor);
  }
```

```html
<ion-list><br/>
 <ion-card  class="oddmes" *ngFor="let user of users">
  <ion-card-content >
     <b>{{user.user_name}} </b>
     <p>{{user.feedback}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
 </ion-list>
```

it will update the color which satisfy the condition at the end of the loop

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to use color attribute ? then I will give you simple logic

Comment: yes @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: Why dont you use [ng-class] instead?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use :

```
<div [color]="item.userType == 'private' ? 'primary' : 'secondary'"> 
Dynamic color 
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have much time write whole code properly. This is simple solution for you

Comment: what if I have more than 3 conditions

Comment: try with switch case in component and bind it with color property.

Answer (score 2):

1. `NgStyle` directive lets you set a given DOM elements style properties.

   `[ngStyle]="{'background-color':user.userType === 'private' ? 'green' : 'red' }"`
2. `NgClass` directive allows you to set the CSS class dynamically for a DOM element.

   `[ngClass]="{'text-success':user.userType === 'private'}"`
3. Also you can create your own custom function like

   `[ngStyle]="{'color':getColor(user.userType)}"`